# How to get permission for camera in ios version 14.7.1?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

14.6 version works well with key NSCameraUsageDescription in plist. After ios update camera broken down, in google didn't find any solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous version on first request to AVCaptureDevice system ask a permission.

After update call for AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your value for `NSCameraUsageDescription` is not empty

With empty string it'll work in debug bug crash in release